# Getting "NameError: name 'Reduction' is not defined" error in Tensorflow 1.13

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, reduction, mean-square-error

I am trying to use def 'tf.losses.mean_squared_error'. But I am getting

```
NameError: name 'Reduction' is not defined
```

I am using TF 1.13. 
Is that some import issue or has there been any update in the tf.losses.mean_squared_error function?

My code is as follows.

```
def reg_loss(pred, GT):
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(
    labels = GT,
    predictions = pred,
    weights=1.0,
    scope=None,
    loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES,
    reduction=Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS)

    return reg_loss
```

Could anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: You should include the complete traceback, just the error at the end doesn't say much.

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Comment: @AlbinDavid sorry, not yet

Comment: @Ashj  added answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS`
this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The complete classes path should be this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/losses/Reduction)

```
tf.compat.v1.losses.Reduction
```

so the solution can be

```
import tensorflow as tf # optional alias
from tf.compat.v1.losses import Reduction
```